# DataGridView Cell Style Read Only On One Machine But Not Another?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a Winforms .NET program and use a property grid to edit the DefaultCellStyle. This works on my development box but I have a test running under VMware and for some reason on this machine it is read only. But, I have ran it under other machines and not seen this before.

I am copying the executable and thus the code and all properties are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The new machine only had .NET 4.0 but not .NET 4.5 installed. When I installed .NET 4.5 then it worked even though it didn't require .NET 4.5 to run. This was the only "side effect" I seen. Very peculiar.